# how to make this code dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization

Well, i have this horrible and long code of js and html, how can i optimize this?
I want to turn all this into something variable ie not having to be repeating all the code

in the html you can see how I use a href to be able to alternate each month, while in js jquery is used to add the result of the function in each cell

```js
function getVencimientos(){
      $.getJSON("https://maxtechglobal.com/vencimientos/agip/ib.php?cuit="+$("#cuit").val()+"", function(result){
        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
          $.each(result.data[i].vencimientos, function( index, value ) {
              if(index == "ene") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_enero_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.ene;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            } else if(index == "febrero") {
               var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_febrero_admin_agip");
               var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

               var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
               var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
               var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
               var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
               var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

               cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
               cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
               cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.feb;
               cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
               cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
             }  else if(index == "mar") {
                var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_marzo_admin_agip");
                var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

                cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
                cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
                cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.mar;
                cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
                cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
              }  else if(index == "abr") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_abril_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.abr;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            } else if (index == "may") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_mayo_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.may;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            } else if (index == "jun") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_junio_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.jun;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            } else if (index == "jul") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_julio_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.jul;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            } else if (index == "ago") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_agosto_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.ago;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            } else if (index == "sep") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_septiembre_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.sep;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            } else if (index == "oct") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_octubre_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.oct;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            } else if (index == "nov") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_noviembre_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.nov;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            } else if (index == "dic") {
              var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_diciembre_admin_agip");
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.dic;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            }
          });
        }
      });
}
```

```html
  <div class="col-md-4"><h5 style="display:none" id="tituloVenc_agip"></h5>
            <div id="Agip_resultados" style="display:none" class="card card-nav-tabs">
              <div class="header header-info">
                <div class="nav-tabs-navigation">
                  <div class="nav-tabs-wrapper">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-agip-admin" data-tabs="tabs">
                      <li class="active"><a href="enero_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Enero</a></li>
                      <li><a href="febrero_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Febrero</a></li>
                      <li><a href="marzo_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Marzo</a></li>
                      <li><a href="abril_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Abril</a></li>
                      <li><a href="mayo_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Mayo</a></li>
                      <li><a href="junio_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Junio</a></li>
                      <li><a href="julio_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Julio</a></li>
                      <li><a href="agosto_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Agosto</a></li>
                      <li><a href="septiembre_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Septiembre</a></li>
                      <li><a href="octubre_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Octubre</a></li>
                      <li><a href="noviembre_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Noviembre</a></li>
                      <li><a href="diciembre_agip_admin" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Diciembre</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="tab-content tab-content-agip-admin text-center">
                  <div class="tab-pane active" id="enero_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_enero_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="febrero_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_febrero_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="marzo_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_marzo_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="abril_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_abril_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="mayo_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_mayo_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="junio_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_junio_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="julio_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_julio_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="agosto_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_agosto_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="septiembre_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_septiembre_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="octubre_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_octubre_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="noviembre_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_noviembre_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="diciembre_agip_admin">
                    <table class="table" id="tabla_impuestos_diciembre_admin_agip">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Concepto</th>
                            <th>Vencimiento</th>
                            <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    <!--cierra el AGIP    -->
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why not create a single function and just pass the id to it? and use a switch case

Comment: If your code works, and you're just looking to improve it, Code Review is probably a better SE site to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the IDs of your tables in your HTML then you can make the code work a lot easier. You know the index that you are getting is going to correlate with the ID of the table so just make your table IDs the same as your index.

```
function getVencimientos(){
    $.getJSON("https://maxtechglobal.com/vencimientos/agip/ib.php?cuit="+$("#cuit").val()+"", function(result){
        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
            $.each(result.data[i].vencimientos, function( index, value ) {

                var table_abril = document.getElementById("tabla_impuestos_" + index + "_admin_agip");
                var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

                cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
                cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
                cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos[index];
                cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
                cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a switch  case and extract your code as a separate function

```
function getVencimientos(){
      $.getJSON("https://maxtechglobal.com/vencimientos/agip/ib.php?cuit="+$("#cuit").val()+"", function(result){
        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
          $.each(result.data[i].vencimientos, function( index, value ) {
          switch(index)
          {
          case "ene": 
           SetData("tabla_impuestos_enero_admin_agip");
           break;

           case "febrero": 
           SetData("tabla_impuestos_enero_admin_agip");
           break;

             case "mar": 
           SetData("tabla_impuestos_enero_admin_agip");
           break;
           .
           .

          }
```

so on and so forth

and in your SetData function pass the id

```
function SetData(id)
{
var table_abril = document.getElementById(id);
              var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

              var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
              var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
              var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
              var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
              var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

              cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
              cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].concepto;
              cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.dic;
              cell4.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AGIP</label>';
              cell5.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
}
```

something like this

here is a sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/20/

Comment: its good, but this "cell3.innerHTML = result.data[i].vencimientos.dic;" is variable, how can i change "dic"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're in need of a js templating library. A templating library allows you to separate your html from your data and fill in the data. A good one will also handle loops to let you easily render arrays of data. I've had a good experience with [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

From their docs, you might render an array like this:

```
<div id="comments">
  {{#each comments}}
  <h2><a href="/posts/{{../permalink}}#{{id}}">{{title}}</a></h2>
  <div>{{body}}</div>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```